# Is it possible to get a job in US (with H-1B sponsorship) during/after postdoc from USA?

Tags: h1-visa

Postdoc scholars usually come to US on J-1 visa. I know that somehow people who do PhD and postdoc both from US, manage to get a job with H-1B sponsorship in my field of expertise. However, I already have a PhD from Canada and currently looking for postdoc opportunities in Canada as well as USA. Long term employment opportunities are way better in USA in my field. Therefore, I want to move to US for postdoc first. Will it be possible to get an employer who can sponsor H-1B during/after my postdoc in USA? OR is there something which I am missing that makes a difference between me and people who also do their PhD from USA?

Thanks,